# Does Stack Overflow have a special Google integration?

Tags: discussion, google

Does Stack Overflow have a *new* special kind of Google integration?

How does this work? It looks great!

[image: Integrateion]

Comment: I don't see such a thing. Either it's something on your side (e.g. userscript/plugin) or your browser.

Comment: [Related question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360212/4751173) – Google is A/B testing.

Comment: It's an experiment that Google is doing. It's not anything that we're doing or have control over.

Comment: @animuson thanks, it does'nt appear all the time, so it makes thanks.

Comment: @animuson but I do wonder, hasn't Google contacted SE to help with this, or at least give you a head start that such a thing is rolling out? It's a major change that will probably have huge impact, if going live.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've not heard anything about it internally, and that seems like something they'd announce to everyone. We're not the only Q&A platform out there, and I'm sure this would affect other sites like Microsoft's Q&A whatever it's called, or Yahoo Answers. Not just us.

Comment: No, Google is not special-casing Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow has been providing standardised markup (a microformat from Schema.org, a Google-sponsored organisation) for over 5 years now. I've seen these experiments on and off, these are A/B user testing experiments, not yet a generally-available feature.

Comment: Related: [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/233845)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: This is **still a duplicate**, of both [Does Google special-case for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/136397) and the above link. This is nothing new, Google has been running these experiments for years now, and the duplicates show what relationship there is: Schema.org metadata provided by websites that want to be seen as Q&A sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I don't appreciate you just re-opening a post without further discussion. I've been monitoring Google's use of Schema.org data for years, please trust my judgement on this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters repeating my MSO comment: I believe each new feature of Google that affects SO results deserves its own report/discussion here. It's my personal opinion, I can't force it on others, but using my power where I can. Here I happen to have more than on MSO that's all. If others agree with you, they can close this again and I won't pursue this further.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: there is nothing to discuss however. It's a Google A/B experiment, most people actually **won't see it**. The question "Does Google have a special relationship" is **directly addressed** by the other posts. If there was an actual discussion on the Schema.org metadata SE sites provide, that'd be a different matter.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: the question "how does it work" is also directly addressed by [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/233845). So the only correct answers to this question are found in two posts already on this site. I really fail to see why you think this is not a clear cut duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: now, if you want to open up a *new question* that discusses the relative merits of the UI and info Google is picking and the impact that could have on Stack Overflow and other SE sites, perhaps that'd be worthy of discussion (or also off-topic, not judging that tack just yet). But the *very content if this specific question*, is covered by the duplicates you so happily dismissed. I get it that people are enthusiastic that Google is doing these experiments, but do please read the question properly next time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe fresh set of eyes will help, I'll ask others and see.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - If you feel that the other question is a duplicate, then perhaps you should edit it to reflect the current feature and not the old one (although this is not really proper). As it sits, this question is addressing a different feature, although it is similar in nature. Moreover, the title of the other question specifically cites "not showing the top answer", which this new iteration does not suffer from. So, all in all, Shadow Wizard acted appropriately here in my opinion. I also find you rather biased in this situation, as it is your answer on the other post.

Comment: @TravisJ: Thanks for looking! You are looking at the *second* related post; I found Shadow had reopened the post before I could add it to the dupe list. I had duped this post to [Does Google special-case for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/136397), which is not a post I answered. And the litmus test is and always has been: does the other post *answer the question stated here*. And when you have a limited number of experts in a field, you *naturally* end up duping a certain percentage of posts to your own questions, this is hardly bias. I wanted to add the second post becasue it add

Comment: Interesting, Duck duck go has been doing this at least since August when I first noticed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an ongoing experiment that Google is running. They contacted us some time ago and let us know they were interested in running an experiment that showed additional information from our site including answer snippets. At the time they were going to focus it on the mobile app and web experience, but the desktop experience is also included in this round of testing. While Google doesn't need our permission for this, they have been forthcoming and are keeping us in the loop on which experiments they're running, and will be sharing data back on the results of the experiments.  We will continue to strongly advocate for what we think is best for our users, which includes steering them away from experiments or results that we feel is a detriment to new user and community engagement in the ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) . However, I do not like this. It recently rolled out in my area I guess and it makes searching multiple pages much harder. When I search for a problem, I like clicking multiple pages from each site. Prior to this google with show 4-5 pages related to my question for stackoverflow and I would just open each in a tab. This is not possible now without more work